# C sockets: handle variable length packets

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I' m developing a simple client/server application (you can think of an ftp-like program).

Once connected to the server, the client sends a message like this:

```
GET filename
```

The filename length can of course vary. How can i be sure to create a variable enough big to store the filename string?

```
char buffer[512];
recv(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
```

Comment: You can use strcat() with a while untill you have read all the filename

Comment: @Gabson How are you going to `strlen` a buffer that you still have to `malloc`?

Comment: Ups sry missunderstand

Comment: Note: `sizeof(buffer-1)` is terribly wrong

Comment: sizeof(buffer) - 1 would be better

Comment: If you talk TCP, you don't see any packets. You have a continuous stream of bytes. If you talk UDP (not recommended for such application), you have packets but they have finite (and rather small) maximum size. Specify some reasonable fixed length for your protocol.

Comment: no, `sizeof buffer` is enough. and the return value from recv() should be used.

Comment: Why not look at the source code of any webserver?

Comment: FTP == "simple"? I doubt this.

Comment: Thanks, wrote that example code too fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could say file name length will never exceed some number say 128. Then just declare array with that length.

Otherwise first send the length of the file name, and then the file name. Since length of the file name is integer, its length is fixed, hence you know that say first 2 bytes represent the length of the file name (mind enianness). Afterwards, when you read file name length, you can use `malloc` to allocate space enough for the file name.

This seems weird too

```
sizeof(buffer-1)
```

`buffer` decays to pointer of the first element of array, I doubt you want to subtract one from that.

Note: `recv` may receive fewer bytes than requested, so you may have to loop (and parse) till you receive necessary number of bytes.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what i asked for. Sorry for the wrong example, i wrote the code too fast.